# Lookout gives malware scare when initializing phone or after factory reset

Tags: malware, samsung-galaxy-s7, lookout

When initializing my new (not pre-owned) Samsung Galaxy S7 for the first time or for subsequent times after factory resets, the notification shade shows regarding the Lookout app: "Scan complete. 323 apps scanned - all safe. Get advanced protection today!" Tapping that notification makes it attempt to open a window, presumably for Lookout, but it closes immediately and then a grey bubble notification comes up stating: "Malware no longer exists on your phone." Regardless of whether this notification is tapped, Lookout triggers more notifications when other apps finish loading or have updates installed. For me, the next one is, "Scan finished: Google Play Store is safe. Click to activate total protection, or to change settings." Tapping these opens Lookout properly with a Lookout account login prompt. Does this mean malware is/was on my phone or was it merely a poor design choice of words for first-time initialization?

Comment: Probably the Latter. Its branches, so I highly doubt it already had malware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this with 2 new Android LG phones that have Lookout preloaded and got the same behavior. It's not specific to the Samsung Galaxy S7. It's Lookout's poor design choice of words for first-time initialization.